# Where to put a settings file?

Tags: java, android, file, save, filewriter

Okay, so I've got a couple of data files for an android app.  The files contain lists of items and variables for each, so I don't think using the "Key-Value" method would work very well.

I originally had the files in the "raw" folder, but then I learned that you can't write to that location and this file does need to be updatable.  I now have it reading and writing from (afaik) the root directory of my program's internal storage (File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "settings.txt"); ), and that works alright.  But what I'd like to be able to do is have a default settings file that is placed when I install/update the app.

For example, when I was using the "raw" folder, I could put a file in the "raw" directory on my computer and have it show up when I run the app.  Can I get this behaviour with a location my app can also write to, and if so, how?

Edit: OK to try and clarify, what I'm looking for is a location that I can
a) have my app read and write data to on my phone
b) can have a file put in that location when the app is installed/updated, like you can put a file in the raw folder on your PC and have your app able to read it.

I just want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can create a folder within your application's root directory to save your files to. From there, you should be able to create, read, update, and delete files.

```
File dir = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),"directory name");
if(!dir.exists()) {
    try {
        dir.mkdir();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        //deal with exception
    }
}
File settings = new File(dir, "settings.txt");
if(!settings.exists()) {
    try {
        settings.createNewFile();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        //deal with exception
    }
}
```

Maybe this will work for you?

android may throw it's own form of SecurityException

---

I would suggest you create a Java class that creates, reads, and writes to a settings.txt file. If you want to have that class also create a default settings.txt file and make it write that file to the folder of choice if a settings.txt file doesn't exist already.

Comment: Where do I put the file on my computer, so that it will be placed in that folder when the app is installed/updated?  I've tried putting it in development\workspace\...[projectname]\...[directory name]\ where directory name matches the directory my app is using.  I've tried putting it everywhere as just a file which will go into the root directory.

Comment: Is it a file that needs to be generated by the program? Or are you just looking to see how the program responds to the contents of the file? If it is the former, you can make the program create the file with specified contents.

Comment: The program can update the file (and having read and write access to it is a requirement).  This part I have no problem with, it already does that.

I also want the ability to be able to place a starting file in the directory, so I can start with some good data for testing/trouble-shooting, and so that I can put some sample data for new installations.  This is the part that I can't do.  I could put a file in the "raw" directory, but then I couldn't write to it with my app, so I abandoned that approach.

Comment: Re your latest edit:
hard-coding the default settings really doesn't seem like a good approach.  I could theoretically put my default settings in the "raw" directory and have the program copy that to the root directory.  That would be a MUCH nicer approach than hard-coding a whole bunch of entries...but I'd rather find out if there's a better solution.

Comment: I also already have a class that reads and writes the file for the app.  This part is not what I need help with.

Comment: With the way you are talking, I'm going to guess this is meant to be a learning project or something for your own phone (or something to that effect). In that case, yes, that would work. You could add a text file to your project and read the file from there to easily save it to the folder. If that is too much work, your copying idea would probably be easier than another solution.

Comment: No, this is not a project just for me personally.  Yes, being able to figure this out would help me with my troubleshooting, but I also think it is important to start with some data for when other people use the program. And there would be a fair amount of this data, so having lines and lines of code to write this data to a file to start with is just not an acceptable solution.

Comment: "You could add a text file to your project and read the file from there to easily save it to the folder."
Okay, this sounds kind of like what I've been asking in the first place.  Can you elaborate on this.

Comment: You should be able to add a text file to your project (right click src and new > file) name it settings.txt  You should be able to read the contents from it and into a string. If there isn't a file already created in the folder you want, or if it's for an older version, replace or create the file in that folder.